# Ajax call not being made in DataTable when browser refreshes

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am building a DataTable using jquery.dataTables.js version 1.10.0.  I am using serverside processing with pagination and everything is working wonderfully except one thing.  When I refresh the browser (Chrome or IE 10), the  ajax code is not being executed to refresh the table.  Because of that the table is not refreshing either.  If I go back or forward with the browser, it works perfectly.

Is there something special I need to do to force DataTable to reload on a browser refresh?

Here is my dataTable declaration:

```
      var dataTable = table.dataTable({
          "retrieve": true,
          "lengthMenu": [ [10, 30, 50, -1], [10, 30, 50, "All"] ],
          "serverSide": true,
          "paging": true,
          "searching":false,
          "pageLength": 30,
          "columns": [ {
            "sTitle": "col1"
          }, {
            "sTitle": "col2"
          } ],
          "dom": '<"top"if>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
          "ajax": {
              // set up input parameters
              "data": function(data) {
                  var length = table.dataTable().api().page.len();
                  var url = baseUrl + '/' + data.start + '/' + length;
                  table.dataTable().api().ajax.url(url);
                  draw = data.draw;
                  return {};
              },
              "url": baseUrl, //will be reset by data function
              "dataFilter": function(data,type) {

                  var results = {};
                  ....  //reformat the REST response for DataTable

                  return JSON.stringify(results);
              },
              "dataSrc": function(data) {

                  // hide length menu if records are less than minimum display
                  if (data.recordsTotal <= 10) {
                          $('#' + callType + relNcid + '_length').hide();
                      }

                  // hide page menu if all records fit on this page
                  if (data.recordsTotal <= table.dataTable().api().page.len()) {
                      $('#' + callType + relNcid + '_paginate').hide();
                  } else {
                      $('#' + callType + relNcid + '_paginate').show();
                  }
                  table.addClass('table table-condensed');
                  $anchorScroll();
                  return transformRelDataForTable(data.data);
              }
          }
        });
```

This code is being executed on the browser refresh, however, when I put break points at the 'draw' function or 'dataFilter' function it never breaks.

I'm using 
Jquery 1.11.0
AngularJS 1.2.13

Answer (score 0):

I found and fixed the problem. It was external to dataTables. It was cause by a silent failure to access the table. My code:

```
$('#' + relPosition).dataTable({.....});
```

silently failed because the table referenced by jquery did not yet exist because it was part of a ng-repeat clause and Angular had not yet rendered that node on the DOM. In stepping through the dataTable code I noticed that it short circuited everything because the table did not exist (properly so), but it would have been very helpful to have the dataTable code throw an exception in this case. It would have saved me days of trouble.